# Maven properties in multi-module project are reset to default

Tags: maven, maven-2, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I have a question regarding properties in a multi-module project.

Consider the following 3-level project struture:

```
project
+- pom.xml (packaging: pom)        //referred to as super-pom
+- module_group
   +- pom.xml (packaging: pom)     //referred to as group-pom
   +- module
      +-pom.xml (packaging: jar)   //referred to as module-pom
```

In the super-pom I define a property *revision* which gets the default value "unknown".

Additionally I declare and use the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` which is configured to get the svn revision and put it into property *revision*.

Next I configure the `maven-jar-plugin` to write that property into the manifest.

In th module-pom I declare usage of the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` so that is actually executed.

This all works when building the module directly, i.e. executing the module-pom only.
The manifest contains the revision that is reported by the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` as is printed in the console.

However, if I execute the super-pom or group-pom the default value for *revision* is written to the manifest, although the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` gets executed and it retrieves the correct revision (it prints it to the console *before*  the `maven-jar-plugin` runs).

So I have the feeling that I am missing something on property inheritance in multi-module projects.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here? Or could anyone point me to a description of how properties are actually handled in those cases (unfortunately I didn't manage to find a good description yet)?

*Update*

I did some research and a few test runs with debug output (`-X` option) and from what I found so far, I assume my problem is the following:

1) During pom parsing the properties used in the pom are replaced with their values.

Consider this partial pom:

```
<!-- declare the property default value -->
<properties>
  <revision>default</revision>
</properties>

...

<!-- use the property -->
<someconfig>${revision}</someconfig>
```

After the pom is evaluated, it seems to result in a state that would correspond to this:

```
<properties>
  <revision>default</revision>
</properties>

...

<!-- The property seems to be "statically" replaced -->
<someconfig>default</someconfig>
```

2) The plugin that sets the actual property value runs afterwards, even if during the `validate` phase.

Thus the property itself is correctly set to the new value, but it is not read anymore.

3) The plugin that uses `<someconfig>` (in my case it would be the `maven-jar-plugin`) now runs with `<someconfig>default</someconfig>` and thus it doesn't read `revision` at all.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I can only say that declaring buildnumber-maven-plugin and maven-jar-plugin in a super-pom works well for me, no matter whether it is a group build or a targeted build.

Here's a part of this super-pom (a parent for all projects):

```
        <!-- Generate build number -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Attach build number to all jars -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                        <Implementation-Build-Timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</Implementation-Build-Timestamp>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```